# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS two screens working (in mirror mode). Display settings doesn't show option to join displays

Tags: drivers, 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Hardware: Intel NUC10I7FNK2
- CPU: i7-10710U
- GPU: Intel Corporation Comet Lake UHD Graphics (rev 04)

Really new to linux. Have done some working with the terminal and a little programming before so kinda know how things work.

For clarity:

- Both screens are currently working - only in mirror mode [image - dual monitors working in mirror mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odEl2.jpg)
- No option in the display settings to "join" or "single display" [image - settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g9Qy.png)

Help very appreciated. Im looking to join displays. Have to do this setup 15 more times.

Coen

EDIT: This is probably an some error using an external adapter. However this intel nuc spec's state using USB-C to use two displays using an adapter works.

Comment: How are the two screens connected? Are there two hdmi ports -- I have an older NUC with one single hdmi port, and I don't think it can manage what you want. But I can get what I think you want with Ubuntu 20.04.x LTS in a Dell m4800 - one screen is the internal one and the other is my 40 inch TV. I can drag a window from the internal screen to the TV, make it fullscreen and enjoy.

Comment: They are connected as follows: USB-C to HDMI and VGA. HDMI and VGA connect both monitors. They are compatible with the USB-C port and dual screen on intel nuc side.

Comment: Is the 'HDMI and VGA' an external splitter? An adapter? In that case I would guess, that the NUC's graphic chip is not aware of it, and sends only one 'picture' and both screens will receive it. But I am not an expert.

Comment: It is indeed an external splitter. Any ideas on how to make the nuc grapic chip "aware"? This usb-c port should support dual displays.

Comment: Let us hope someone who knows more than I will see your question :-)

Comment: Thanks! I hope too.

Comment: By the way, is there also an HDMI port? In that case, what happens it you connect one screen the HDMI port and the other one via the USB C port and the external splitter?

Comment: There is also an HDMI port. Using HDMI + USB-C to VGA works. Then i can join displays. Third screen arrives tomorrow so need this to work on the adapter USB-C to HDMI and VGA...

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding: It is possible, that when Intel promises that the NUC can feed two monitors, they mean one via the HDMI port and one via the USB C port. You can split the signals, but that will only provide mirroring. However, maybe another adapter might work better, so once again, let us hope someone who knows more than I will see your question :-)

Comment: No, it clearly states 3 monitors supported and that this should work via the usb-c port ;)